# Drupal Google Ad Manager module not showing ads in homepage for anonymous users

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, double-click, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I'm using DFP Small Business for serving ads for my website which is Drupal 6.22 website, and something weird happened, the homepage shows only one ad of total 7 ads for anonymous users, however it shows all ads for logged in users.

Any Ideas? Please, advise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your input filter type. Make sure if you are embedding the Google Ad Javascript in any sort of form or field (node, block, etc), make sure you are using a non-filtered input format. PHP filter works good.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was my fault, that I forgot the aggressive caches, that caches the head section tightly, and the head section contains calls to the GA_googleAddSlot() function.

So, when the function GA_googleFillSlot() is called to fill the block with an ad, nothing is shown cause nothing were fetched from the beginning.

Thanks anyway guys.